# Prompt user for uninstallation password during application uninstallation from Add/Remove programs

Tags: windows-installer, uninstallation, password-protection

I have written one application in which I require to prompt the user for password when the user wants to uninstall it from the Add/Remove programs. The user should be able to uninstall the application only if the password is correct.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I am new to MSI. I have searched a lot for password protected uninstallation but I am not getting anything. I am using Orca to modify propertirs of msi file and not yet found any property which can set uninstallation password.

Comment: During installation I am asking the users to enter unistallation password and saving it in encrypted form into registry. Plz help me in it. Any help will be appreciated.